# AWS CloudWatch Rules fail to trigger lambda functions after the alias being deleted and created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to make the [alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html) of an AWS lambda function point to another version.

Since I can't find how to update an alias using AWS management console. I deleted and created the alias.

But then I found that all the cloudwatch rules that trigger the lambda function failed to work:

[image]

Is it possible to recreate the alias of a lambda function without breaking cloudwatch rules?

Where can I find the log for *FailedInvocations* of cloudwatch rules? I'd like to dig deeper to know the reason of the failure.

Doesn't AWS management console have the [update-alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-alias.html) button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the AWS Management console you can change version number tagged with the alias.

To change the version number of your existing alias, got to the Lambda Function and select alias from the **Switch versions/aliases** dropdown. from the **Aliases** section you can change the version number, as well as you can divert traffic between two versions based on based on weights (%).

[image]

After creating the new Lambda function alias you can just re-select the alias from the existing CloudWatch without breaking the rules.

Comment: Thank you. I've found the buttons. They are located at the bottom of the web page. I think this is not intuitive.